# restoring R environment to condition prior the loading of a package

Tags: r, package, environment, restore, detach

In a script I need to load packages tydiverse and gdistance.

gdistance actually loads several other packages and overall mask some functions of the tydiverse (e.g. select).

I tried to rearrange the script by loading the gdistance only when needed and having the related lines at the end of the script.

Anyway one of the very last line I need still use the function tydiverse::select, which is then not found and it throws an error.

Is there a way to make a copy of the R environment before loading the gdistance package so that I can then restore the environment as it was before loading the pakage that induce the problem?

Comment: You've got the answer in your question -- use `dplyr::select()` (the home of the `select()` 'generic') rather than `select()` in your script.

Comment: oh ok... didn't know the :: could do that... I'll try

Comment: Great, it works!

Comment: `tidyverse` is just a package for loading lots of other functions, so you need `dplyr::select`, not `tidyverse::select`. You'll also have trouble if you're spelling it in your code the way it's misspelled in your question

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternatives:

**1)** Simply load tidyverse second since the most recently loaded name takes precdence.

```
library(gdistance)
library(tidyverse)
```

**2)** `select` actually comes from the raster package used by gdistance, not from gdistance itself.  Also, in R version 3.6+ `library` has an `exlude=` argument to exclude loading specified names.  Thus we can write the follwoing to ensure that `select` will refer to dplyr.

```
# needs R 3.6+ 
library(tidyverse)
library(raster, exclude = "select")
library(gdistance)
```

**3)** Use `dplyr::select` to force `select` to be used from dplyr.

**4)** `detach` gdistance and raster before using `select` and load them back in afterwards (if you still need them).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gdistance)

# ... select refers to select from raster

detach("package:gdistance")
detach("package:raster")

# ... select refers to select from dplyr

library(gdistance)

# ... select refers to select from raster
```